# in the Arc , Block in what circumstance is __NSMallocBlock__ or __NSStackBlock__ or __NSGlobalBlock__？

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, block

```
-(id)getBlockArray
{
    int val = 10;

    return  [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:^{NSLog(@"1-%d",val);},^{NSLog(@"2-%d",val);} ,^{NSLog(@"3-");}, nil];
}
```

Comment: id obj = [self getBlockArray];
  NSLog(@"%@",obj);
the log is(look,they are different,i want know why?):
2015-03-19 14:39:26.968 BTLE Transfer[28037:3241024] (
    "<__NSMallocBlock__: 0x7ffeb3d9b940>",
    "<__NSStackBlock__: 0x7fff55da7bf0>",
    "<__NSGlobalBlock__: 0x109e5d120>"
)

Comment: Please edit your question. There is normally no need to comment on your questions to add information. Add a question that is a full sentence to the post as well. The title has a question mark but doesn't explain your problem in a clear way.

Answer (score 7):

Blocks that don't capture any variables are global blocks. Since all instances of the block are the same, the compiler can just allocate one copy statically for the life of the program.

Blocks that capture variables (closures) are either stack or heap (malloc) blocks. Blocks start out on the stack, as stack blocks. When a stack block is copied for the first time, it is moved to the heap. Copying a heap block does not create another copy; but simply retains it.

The third one being a global block is obvious, since it doesn't capture any variables. The first two capture variables. Apparently, the first one is copied and the second one isn't.

The ARC specification does not guarantee that either of the first two blocks are copied. However, the ARC compiler is allowed to insert additional copies if it wants. (Copying a block can't hurt.)

I believe the current versions of the Clang ARC compiler conservatively inserts copy's when an expression of block-pointer type is passed to a parameter of non-block object pointer type. This is a good idea because APIs that take non-block object pointers generally only retain them when they need to store them, rather than copy as is needed for blocks. Copying them beforehand prevents unsafeness from this situation. That explains the copying of the first argument. What about the second one? My guess is that it's because it's varargs instead of an explicit parameter (`-[NSArray initWithObjects:]` takes one parameter of type `id` and then has varargs, `...`), and Clang's rule about copying when passing perhaps does not apply to varargs (since it doesn't know the "parameter type").

You should always copy blocks before passing it to an API that takes normal object pointers and stores them, like `-[NSArray initWithObjects:]`, because copying is not guaranteed.